# javaFx: create file in current directory

Tags: file, filenames

I am trying to create a file in current directory, the file name is based on the application name and the date, so far i am doing this but when i check the folder i dont see the file so the file is not created ...some one can help me please?

```
public File file;
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
       Date date = new Date();
       String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);
       String format = "Topology_"+ currentDate+".log";
       String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
       String path = userDirectory+"\\"+format;
       file = new File(path);
       if((file.exists()))
       {
          System.out.println("file created");
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `file.exits()` does not create the file, what you are looking for is

```
boolean file.createNewFile()
```

Also

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

does not return the current working directory, but the user folder.

Also i would suggest using the platform independent slash '/' instead of the windows only backslash '\'.

Comment: thank u for the answer, i know that file.exists() checks if the file does exist, but  file = new File(path) is the command to create the file right?

Comment: No, it only creates a file object which represents an existing or non existing file.

Answer (score 0):

since I fixed the error I"ll provide an answer maybe it will help someone else :
 file = new File(path)  creates an instance of the file in memory, so the file doesn't exist on the disk yet. The error here is that my filename contain ":" character and that is forbidden , only when i created a BufferedWriter with an OutputStreamWriter i saw the file in the current folder(System.getProperty("user.dir")).